# Xampp getting Out of Memory with composer command

Tags: php, linux, macos, xampp

After installing latest version of `xampp 8.0.9` when i open terminal from `xampp` panel i have another operating system as `Debian`,

```
uname -a -r
Linux debian 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

now after navigating to `php` project inside `htdocs` folder i try to use `composer upadte` to install and upadte `composer.json` packages but i get this error:

```
composer update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 798220288) (tried to allocate 32134463 bytes) in /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 459

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 798220288) (tried to allocate 32134463 bytes) in /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 459
```

when i get this error i try to change `memory_limit` into `php.ini` file, then i run this command:

```sh
php --ini
```

output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/lampp/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

here `memory_limit` is `-1` and as i installed `php 8.0.9` it doesn't has `php` folder inside `/etc/` and i have only `php 7.3`

```
php -v
```

output:

```
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 09:12:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

opening `php.ini` inside `php 7.3` folder to change `memory_limit`, this option value has `-1` too

now how can i increase `memory_limit` and resolve this problem?

finally running this command don't take me any output or result:

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M /usr/bin/composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update
```

so that the limit is set independently of the ini file.

And according to `php --ini` your php.ini file for php 8 is in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini not under /etc/

Comment: then try the full path to your composer file

Comment: i tested before

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue whenever I try to use seeder in laravel to upload 1 lakh data at the same time to

1. first you can try to PHP chunk function to try to upload few data

> ```
> foreach (array_chunk($object_array,1000) as $t)  
> {
>     DB::table('table_name')->insert($t); 
> }
> ```

and then run `php artisan o:c`

2. run command in your terminal

> `free -m`

this is free your memory